# Contextual or Drop down window

Tags: .net, winforms, winapi

I am elaborating on how to set the window style to behave like the context menu or the combo-box drop down list - to be able to close when user clicks outside the window area or presses Escape but I have found no clue.

I have already used the ToolStripDropDownButton to simulate this behavior quite well but there is one big issue that the parental window loses focus and I am unable to restore it for the time the drop down window is active.
Any help?

Answer (score 0):

In the event: "From.Deactivate" Do: "Me.Close"

Comment: This is no sollution either because I need to pass the focus to the other control (as stated above). Newertheless I have found the sollution in allowing the popup window to take the focus and pass all the messages to the parent control. This will serve the purpose. Thanks for an answer.